# Django puts new line at end of variable where flask does not

Tags: python, django

Righto, so i've been pulling my hair out over this one for a bit. It's not absolutely crucial to my application but it makes everything look nicer.

I'm in the process of converting my Flask Application to Django (As to fit in with my other related Django Web Apps).

Everything has come accross nicely and i have almost all the functionality as my original application (rather easy when it uses mostly the same code).

Whats happening is my Jquery requests an ID from the Django / Flask view, and returns a result based on the output of that view. This works absolutely fine.

What isn't working is the 'catches' i have which are written in the Jquery file (say if an invalid ID is entered).

Flask returns

```
No service assigned to that ID|
```

as i want, where as Django returns

```
No service assigned to that ID
|
```

(note: no pipe "|", actually returns, thats just to show you where the cursor is after the value is returned)

This seems like a small difference, but it is currently breaking my code and i cant see another way to fix it.

As you can see Django outputs the value with an extra line.
Here is a sample of the code i am using (pretty much the same in both)

**python: (Flask and Django)**

```
error = "No service assigned to that ID"
```

**JQuery**

```
(AJAX stuff above here. returned value is 'reply')

if((reply) == 'No service assigned to that ID') {
  $('#spinner').empty().append("No service assigned to that ID");
}
else {....}
```

Comment: How do you return the value in Django? `HttpResponse` or via a template?

Comment: `return HttpResponse(template.render(contextelements))`

Comment: Can you post your template code?

Comment: `template` is the lookup.html file i've made. Same as the Flask one as the tags are the same. `contextelements` is the list of variables being passed through. Will post template code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.strip()` in Python or `string.trim()` in Javascript to remove any leading and trailing whitespace, including newlines.

```
# Will remove leading/trailing whitespace from any response
return HttpResponse(template.render(contextelements).strip())
```

or

```
// Will compare with the trimmed result (tough `reply` is not changed)
if(reply.trim() == 'No service assigned to that ID') {
```

Which one you should use depends on whether you want to strip whitespace from all responses or just this comparison.

Comment: Awesome. I like your way more than mine. Feels more absolute. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I decided just to work with it.

Changed "==" to ".contains" so it does not have to be an absolute match, just conatain the same text.

```
if((reply).contains('No service assigned to that ID')) {
  $('#spinner').empty().append("No service assigned to that ID");
}
else {....}
```

Comment: Just an FYI. this solution only seems to work with Firefox. Chrome and IE really do not like it.